# What is the Arabian Scale in the key of G? What instruments are tuned to the Arabian Scale?

Tags: scales, learning

I read about a Native American Flute tuned to the Arabian Scale in the key of G. I know the NAF is tuned to a pentatonic scale but am not familiar with the Arabian Scale. Does it have 5 notes? 7 notes?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that the scale you are referring to would be:

`G Ab B C D Eb F# G`

It is also called **Gypsy Major**, and in music theory, it is often called [*double harmonic major*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_harmonic_scale).

Enjoy playing with it - it's a really fun sound!

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found an Arabic scale. In G , the notes would be G A B C Db Eb F G. A whole tone scale, except for the C put in extra instead of going B>C#/Db.

Comment: O.k. if this is wrong, would the downvoter provide a more accurate answer, please, and reasons why it's unacceptable...